# Set <a> tag to the current <div>

Tags: jquery

i wrap an  tag from an image to the Div tag. It works without a problem. But the a tag wraps not the current Div. To each Div is the same a tag.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="link-container">
    <div class="content-inner">
        <h1>headline</h1>
        <p>Copy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-inner">
        <figure class="image_container float_above">
            <a href="index.php/home.html">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </a>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="link-container">
    <div class="content-inner">
        <h1>headline</h1>
        <p>Copy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-inner">
        <figure class="image_container float_above">
            <a href="index.php/home2.html">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </a>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="link-container">
    <div class="content-inner">
        <h1>headline</h1>
        <p>Copy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-inner">
        <figure class="image_container float_above">
            <a href="index.php/home3.html">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </a>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Output:

```
<a href="index.php/home.html"><a><a><div class="link-container">
    <div class="content-inner">
        <h1>headline</h1>
        <p>Copy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-inner">
        <figure class="image_container float_above">

        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></figure>
    </div>
</div></a></a></a>

<a href="index.php/home.html"><a><a><div class="link-container">
    <div class="content-inner">
        <h1>headline</h1>
        <p>Copy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-inner">
        <figure class="image_container float_above">

        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></figure>
    </div>
</div></a></a></a>
```

But i want this as output

```
<a href="index.php/home.html"><div class="link-container">
    <div class="content-inner">
        <h1>headline</h1>
        <p>Copy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-inner">
        <figure class="image_container float_above">

        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></figure>
    </div>
</div></a>

<a href="index.php/home2.html"><div class="link-container">
    <div class="content-inner">
        <h1>headline</h1>
        <p>Copy</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-inner">
        <figure class="image_container float_above">

        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></figure>
    </div>
</div></a>
```

An the jQuery Script

```
$('.image_container').each(function () {
    var myFigure = $(this);
    var myAnchor = $(myFigure).find('a');
    var myImage = $(myAnchor).find('img');
    var newImage = $(".link-container");
    console.log(myFigure);
    $(myFigure).append(myImage).before(myAnchor);   
    var href = $(myAnchor).attr('href');    
    $('.image-inner a').remove();   
    $(".link-container").wrap($("<a/>").attr("href", href));

});
```

And the fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/db63f0zh/47/

I would like the following: link1 to div1, link2 to div2...

Comment: I don't understand what you want. What shall be wrapped, what not?

Comment: i want <a href="link1"><div class="link-container">1</div></a><a href="link2"><div class="link-container">2</div></a>.

and not <a href="link1"><div class="link-container">1</div></a><a href="link1"><div class="link-container">2</div></a>

Comment: what about and not, go on?

Comment: updated my answer & demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your code refer to all elements in document.

```
$('.image-inner a').remove();   
$(".link-container").wrap($("<a/>").attr("href", href));
```

Use this instead to refer to child and parent of image_container

```
$(this).find('.image-inner a').remove();   
$(this).parents(".link-container").wrap($("<a/>").attr("href", href));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be as simple as

```
$('.link-container').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $imgct = $(this).find('.image_container');
    $imgct.append($imgct.find('img'));
    $(this).wrap($(this).find('.image_container a'))
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vqb0hmmm/)

In your case in some of your selectors you are not using the problem context.

Answer (score 0):

I think just this much should work for you

```
$('.link-container').each(function(){
   var href = $(this).find('.image-inner a').attr('href'); //Get the href of anchor in image-inner
   $(this).find('.image-inner a img').unwrap(); //remove the parent of img in image-inner
   $(this).wrap('<a href="'+href+'"></a>'); //wrap the whole div in anchor
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/db63f0zh/49/)

**NOTE:** Assuming you need to wrap all 3 divs.